# Option field show allow empty string

Tags: jquery, regex

I have regular expression for URL and it is validating properly. But this field is optional. when i submit without entering URL means it is validating. In my case if user types means URL should validate otherwise empty string should submit means should not validate.

Below is my code,

```
$.validator.addMethod('url', function(value, element) {
          var regex = new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
          var key = value;

          if (!regex.test(key)) {
             return false;
          }
          return true;
      }, "Please enter valid URL");
```

Comment: put one more condition for checking a value is not blank`if(key != '') {if (!regex.test(key)) {
             return false;
          }}
`

Comment: @Curiousdev thx ur code also working fine.

Comment: You're welcome please accept AthMav's answer if you find it's helpful to u

Answer (score 2):

```
$.validator.addMethod('url', function(value, element) {
          var regex = new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
          var key = value;

          if (key=='' || regex.test(key)) {
             return true;
          }
          return false;
      }, "Please enter valid URL");
```